# How to restrict .click to first image to avoid fetching all images stored in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have multiple images that are returned into this div (Works as expected).

```
<div class="go" id="container"></div>
```

This code then lets the user click on one of the images and it loads it into a modal popup. This works, but instead of capturing one image it takes every image returned to the container.

How can I make it just take the first image clicked on? or stop it taking multiple images?

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.go').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    $('.go').click(function (e) { // Button which will activate our modal
                        $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
                        $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                            animation: 'fade', // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                            animationspeed: 600, // how fast animtions are
                            closeonbackgroundclick: true, // if you click background will modal close?
                            dismissmodalclass: 'close' // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
```

This is how the images are captured.

```
                       _.each(friends, function (item) {
                            // using a wrapper so the user can click the pic or the name
                            var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper" data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"></div>');
                            wrapper.append('<img class="images" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
                            wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
                            $('#container').append(wrapper);
                        });
```

Here is the pop up box

```
 <!---Pop up box with info about the badge and options for user to complete-->
            <div id="modal">
                <div id="heading">
                    Award your friend this badge!?
                </div>

                <div id="content_pb">

                    <div id="badgeselect">
                    </div>

                    <p>This will be text that describes the badge
                        <br>and the reason for awarding it</p>

                    <form action="#" method="get">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Select friend" id="username" required/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Add comment" id="email" required/>

                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </form>

                    <a id="send" class="button green close">
                        <img src="images/tick.png">Yes, do it now!</a>

                    <a href="http://kudosoo.com/JQUERYYTEST/dannyboy.html" class="button red close">
                        <img src="images/cross.png">No, Iâm insane!</a>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do the images also have class "go"?

Comment: Where's the reference to the image located? Can you post that as well?

Comment: @FredFrancisco I've added that code as requested

Comment: @Dano007 try replacing the "$('.go').click(function (e) {" to "$('.go div.wrapper').click(function (e) {" -> this means that you're hooking the click event on the wrapper instead of the parent container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to file the click event on a particular image `('.go img').click` instead of the images container `('.go').click`, so instead of loading whole container html or images it would load a single image element to the modal popup box.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.go').on('click','img',function (e) {
 $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
  $('#modal').reveal({
    animation: 'fade',
    animationspeed: 600,
    closeonbackgroundclick: true,
    dismissmodalclass: 'close'
   });
  return false;
});
});
```

Comment: thanks, this seems the cloest answer to the solution. The only thing that happens is when I use your code the actual .click is'nt working over the image any longer?

Comment: please use jQuery event delegation to trigger the click function on the dynamically generated elements(images here). I have updated the code above please see.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target only the first image in the set of images you can use `.first()` in jquery.

Instead of this line

```
 $('.go').click(function (e) {
```

Use like below. It will target only the first image listed under the container.

```
 $('.go img').first().click(function (e) {
```

[**Simple Demo to Explain the Functionality**](http://jsfiddle.net/shS34/)

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand correctly, do you only need one image to respond to 'click' event?

Here, you bind the event to `div.go` which is the container of a set of image elements, either this `div` or its descendants can trigger the event due to the event bubble. Check this jQuery doc for **[event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**, especially the section **Direct and delegated events**

> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event occurs on the selected elements, 
>   whether it occurs directly on the element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.

Here your case is 'direct', you directly bound `div.go` with `click` event. So clicking any image will also trigger popup window.

if You only want to affect one image, one way to do it is just to directly bound event to this particular image element. Hope this will help you.